# Why won't figure.area = ... not work? Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, function, class, struct, func

```
struct Shape{

    struct Rectangle {
        var length = 0
        var width = 0
        var area: Float = 0

    }

    struct Square {
        var length = 0
        var width = 0
        var area: Float = 0

    }

    func area(length: Float, width: Float) -> Float {
        return length * width
    }

}

var figure = Shape.Rectangle()
figure.width = 2; figure.length = 3

figure.area = Shape.area(figure.length,figure.width)
```

Why won't figure.area = ... not work? It allows me to write that in xCode but it doesn't run properly in the PlayGround. Can you declare a function inside of a struct? If yes, how do I declare this (`figure.area = Shape.area(figure.length,figure.width)`) properly?

Comment: You have no classes there actually.

Comment: I mean structs. lol, thanks.

Comment: `area(length:width:)` is an instance method, but you're trying to call it on a type. Also the `area` property is of type `Int`, and `area(length:width:)` returns a `Float` (and has `Float` arguments which you're trying to pass `Int`s into). You're also missing the argument labels from the method call. Apart from all that, there's nothing wrong with it at all!

Comment: @Hamish then what is the right answer? `figure.area = Shape.area(figure.width, figure.length)` still gives me an error even when I write `var area: Float = 0`

Comment: You have another issue. Even if you fix everything @Hamish stated (you should post that as an answer), you end up with an `area` method that will only work for very specific shapes. What happens when you add a `Triangle` or `Circle` shape?

Comment: I still don't understand what Hamish is saying though. @rmaddy What is so bad if I call the method on a value? figure.area is a value...

Comment: And why does each sub-struct have an `area` property? The `area` should be a calculated property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven initialised an instance of Shape when you call area, so the compiler will be confused.

You can either initialise a Shape instance and then call area

```
Shape().area(etc...)
```

Or make the area function a static function, then you can call it like you have been (a much better option anyways)

E.g.

```
struct Shape{

....

    static func area(length: Float, width: Float) -> Float {
        return length * width
    }

}
```

Also, with swift 3, all arguments must be explicitly written unless there is an underscore before them in the function declaration. So you function call should look like this

```
figure.area = Shape.area(length: figure.length, width: figure.width)
```